# include template data while using single send | Twilio SendGrid

Tags: python, email, twilio, sendgrid

I am trying to send an email with the following constraints:

1. the email is a newsletter, and thus follows a certain template, the sender just needs to fill in the template data (which are a simple JSON object)
2. I need to send to a list of contacts that is defined in SendGrid and has its listID

I have tried two things:

1. sending a normal email using a dynamic template while trying to have the recipient be a `list_id` but the API doesn't seem to support such a request as included in the [api reference](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send)
2. creating a design and then using single send to send to a list ( which has successfully worked) since the api includes adding a design_id and a list_id. but the thing is I cannot fill the data as I was able to do with the dynamic template

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid support answered:

Inserting dynamic information in the marketing campaigns is possible with:

- [custom fields](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/managing-contacts/custom-fields)
- [substitution tags](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/substitution-tags).

The [handlebars docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars) are clear -even in an indirect way- after all:

> Twilio SendGrid [Dynamic Transactional Templates](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-templates) and [Marketing
> Campaigns designs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/working-with-marketing-campaigns-email-designs) support the Handlebars templating language to render
> the [Personalizations](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations) you send via the API and the [Substitution Tags](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/substitution-tags)
> **stored on your Marketing Campaigns contacts**.

`Personalizations` are featured **only** in the [Mail Send API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#body) which is different from the [New Marketing Campaigns API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/single-sends/create-single-send).